# How can I extend a word with a loop with Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I'm a beginner and I'm working on an assignment where I want Python to use user input and extend the word.

If user input is monkey the output (print) should be: m-oo-nnn-kkkk-eeeee-yyyyyy

This is my start but it only outputs: m-o-n-k-e-y

Do you have any hints on how I can go forth? https://codeshare.io/8p6nB4

```
    inp = input("Give me a word to extend: ")
    index = -len(inp)
    ext_inp = ''
    for letter in inp:
        if index < 0:
            ext_inp += inp[index] + '-'
            index += 1
        print(ext_inp)
```

Comment: `inp[index]` is going to be mostly the same as `letter` so you could use that instead. Hints: What variable are you using to keep track of how many times the letter should be repeated? `'a' * 3 == 'aaa'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
word_to_be_extended = input("give me a word to extern:")
word_after_extend = ''
for i in range(len(word_to_be_extended)):
    word_after_extend += word_to_be_extended[i] * (i+1)
    if i != len(word_to_be_extended)-1:
        word_after_extend += '-'
print(word_after_extend)
```